# how can I spot if a callable is a generator?

Tags: python, python-3.11

**Context**

for testing purposes, I would like to trace all calls to the methods of an object.

right now: I managed to write the following loop:

```py
def instrument_obj(obj):
    for k in dir(obj):
        try:
            method = getattr(obj, k, None)
            if not callable(method):
                continue
            # skip reserved words:
            if k.startswith("__"):
                continue

            wrapped = my_wrapper(method)
            setattr(obj, k, wrapped)
            print(f"-- instrumented {k}")
        except:
            pass
```

which works for regular methods.

**Problem**
The first issue I encountered with my code is with generators:

Right now `my_wrapper(...)` looks like that:

```py
def my_wrapper(fn):
    def _w(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"-- called {fn.__qualname__}")
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return _w
```

but this breaks generators: since my wrapper doesn't `yield`, a caller can't iterate on it anymore.

For generators, it should do something closer to this:

```py
def my_wrapper(gen):
    def _w(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"-- called {gen.__qualname__}")
        for itm in gen(*args, **kwargs):
            yield itm
    return _w
```

**Question**

How can I spot if the callable I got from my object is a generator ?

Comment: You mean like `ret = my_wrapper(); print(is_a_generator(ret)` and how to implement `is_a_generator` function? It's simple `hasattr(ret, '__iter__')` or something like that.

Comment: Can you provide some sort of reproducible example that can be used for testing to verify possible solutions? Generator functions return a generator when you call them, not the values. It seems like your wrapper should still work with generators without special code.

Comment: @KamilCuk I think the goal is to determine if the argument passed to `my_wrapper` will, *when* called, return a generator or not, not call the function then test the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `inspect.isgeneratorfunction` to determine if the function returns a `generator`.

```
def my_wrapper(fn):
    if inspect.isgeneratorfunction(fn):
        def _w(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"-- called {fn.__qualname__}")
            for itm in fn(*args, **kwargs):
                yield itm
    else:
        def _w(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"-- called {fn.__qualname__}")
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return _w
```